# Dictionary values are not getting replaced. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, types, iteration

<sup>This question has been revised to implement suggestions from comments, simplify, and hopefully reduce confusion.</sup>

I have a dictionary through which I am trying to iterate and replace values. Some of those values are lists and should be replaced by floats.

I'm trying to figure out why the values in this dictionary are not getting reassigned to `1.0`

```
test_data = {
    "Apple": [1, 2],
    "Pear": 3.4,
    "Cherry": [5, 6]
}

for key, value in test_data.items():
    test_data[value] = 1.0
    
print(test_data)
```

I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I do not know why an attempt would be made to hash it instead of reassigning `value`.

Comment: `b = 1.0` is just reassigning that name, it has no impact on the dictionary. Try `test_data[a] = 1.0`.

Comment: Did you try: `test_data[a] = 1.0`? Its not clear what other code you have tried that gives you errors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. How can I target the `b` slots of the dictionary? Because it's the values, not the keys, that I am trying to change.

Comment: You can do that exactly the way shown in the comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I'm sorry. I just realized `test_data[b] = 1.0` is what triggers `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`...I had been doing it like that, but mistakenly thinking the error was triggered by changing `test_data`

Comment: That's because `b` is the *value*, so you're creating a new pair in the dictionary not changing the value of an existing one. If you used better names (even just `key, value`) it would be more obvious that was a mistake.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. How can I target the existing one instead of creating a new pair?

Comment: The way we keep telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some python basics, it is very well explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20keys#dict) (also check this page about [view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20keys#dict-views)), and googling `python dictionary` will give you plenty of examples.

However, I think you want to do something like the following:

```
In [29]: test_data = {
    ...:     "Apple": [1, 2],
    ...:     "Pear": 3.4,
    ...:     "Cherry": [5, 6]
    ...: }
    ...:
    ...: for k in test_data.keys():
    ...:     test_data[k] = 1.0
    ...:

In [30]: test_data
Out[30]: {'Apple': 1.0, 'Pear': 1.0, 'Cherry': 1.0}
```

First of all, you don't really do anything with the values, so you can simply iterate over the keys. Once you have the keys, you can reassign `test_data[k]` to any value you want.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works perfectly. And I'm looking at the links you included. But I don't see an explanation for why when the *values* are what I want to change, I *"don't really do anything with the values"* in the code, but target the *keys* instead. Surely I can't be the only one confused by this.

Comment: Wait... I think I get it now. I was thinking of key:value pairs like tiny two-item lists. But when I think of each key as a variable, and the value as ...well, as the *value assigned* to that variable, then it makes sense! It's not that we are targeting index[0] and mysteriously hitting index[1]. Values are "inside", not "beside" the keys!

Comment: When you do `for k in d.keys()` or `for k,v in d.items()` you get a VIEW OBJECT back (think of it as a list of k,v pairs), not the actual keys and values of the dict. So doing `v = x` will change an item of the view object, not the dictionary. To change the dictionary, you need to explicitly manipulate it. I guess, it is confusing for newcomers but it is really well documented and there are plenty of examples on how to iterate over and modify dictionaries.